# Entity Framework - related ICollection getting materialized into HashSet

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco, hashset, entitycollection

I use EntityFramework POCO + proxies + lazy loading in my project. Today I was pretty surprized to see that the class `Transaction` has its related collection `Rows` materialized into `HashSet` (instead of `EntityCollection`). I need `EntityCollection` for tracking changes in the collection.

```
public class Transaction
{
    public virtual ICollection<TransactionRow> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

However other entity classes have their related collection materialized into `EntityCollection`.

I am loading the `Transaction` through `ObjectQuery`, so it should be in the context. The proxy for the object is also created.

Could anyone tell - how does Entity Framework decide what to use - HashSet or EntityCollection? Why some thing become HashSets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change tracking proxy is created only when these two conditions are met:

- POCO class is public, non-sealed and non-abstract
- **All** persisted properties (with getter and setter) are marked as virtual

Comment: Ouch, I just inspected the class once more and realized that the collection was not marked as virtual :) Thanks for the hint!